# Nsnumber out of scope problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsnumber

I am trying to make **NSNumber *percent** to get the integer value **percentint** but it keeps making it **out of scope.**. The **Nslog** logs are like this:

> The value of integer num is 4
>
> The value of integer num is with NsNumber
>   78910432

My code is this:

> **In my header file:**

```
int percentint;  
NSNumber *percent;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSNumber *percent; //tried without using this too
```

> **In my .m file:**

```
@synthesize percent; //tried without using this too

percentint=4;

NSLog(@"The value of integer num is %i", percentint);

percent= [NSNumber numberWithInt:percentint];

percent= [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:percentint]; //tried without using this too. 

[percent autorelease]; //tried without using this too.

NSLog(@"The value of integer num is with NsNumber %i", percent);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
percentint=4;
NSLog(@"The value of integer num is %i", percentint);
self.percent= [NSNumber numberWithInt:percentint];
NSLog(@"The value of integer num is in array %@", self.percent);
NSLog(@"The value of integer num is in array %d", [self.percent intValue]);
```

leaving the @synthesize percent; in.

Comment: It works but this does not work still.
PassedArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
[PassedArray addObject:self.percent];

Comment: these are very simple Objective C questions, i would suggest reading a beginner's tutorial or work through a book and its examples. I'd suggest Learn Objective-C on the Mac by Knaster and Dalrymple. (Apress Publishing)

Comment: @Bugra, your comment makes no sense at all - try to rephrase. You are suddenly introducing an array not mentioned in your original question.

Comment: Yes my original problem was not the array problem and i did not want to make a new question. I am trying to make Nsnumber go into my array. Shall i make a new question or edit my original question?

Comment: @Bugra Yes, you should first try to find similar questions on NSNumbers stored in NSArray. If none are found that match your issue, you should ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

User @Felz is correct.  in order to get the *value* of a `NSNumber`, you must retrieve it with a method call:

```
int percentInt = 95;
NSNumber *percent = [NSNumber numberWithInt:percentInt];
int myint = [percent intValue];
```

What you did instead, was print out the pointer address for `percent`

```
NSLog(@"Percent Value: %d",[percent intValue]);
NSLog(@"Percent Address: 0x%X",percent);
```

Remember that `NSNumber *percent` means percent is a *pointer* not a value.

Comment: @Till, I try.  The more you teach, the more you learn, the more you automatically remember when coding.  :D

Answer (score 2):

Like the other user insinuated, `NSNumber` is not an integer as you are trying to call it in the last NSLog. to get the int value out of a NSNumber, use `[percent intValue]`.

Another side note: you don't need to initialize percent twice. The first call `numberWithInt:` is like doing an alloc/init/release.

Also, never release an object before you are done with it.